# how to make multiple join in room android

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I have a base. It has 4 tables. Each is parental to the other.
I need to get all the others by the id of the first one (A) and also delete everything at once.

```
A (id)
B(id, parentId) - (a.id = b.parentId)
C(id, parentId) (b.id = c.parentId
D(id, parentId) (c.id = d.parentId)

A -> list B -> list C -> list D
```

I use the room and I don’t understand how to create such a common entity

in SQL write like this:

```
SELECT  a._id, b._id, c._id, d._id from a 
LEFT JOIN  b on a._id = b.parent_id
LEFT JOIN  c on b._id = c.parent_id 
LEFT JOIN  d on c._id = d.parent_id 
WHERE a._id = 1


data class FullEntity(
    @Embedded
    val a: A,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "_id", entityColumn = "parent_id", entity = 
    B::class)
    val listB: List<B>

  // what next? 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // what next?

That would be last.

First

```
data class CWithD(
    @Embedded
    val c: C,
    @Relation(....)
    val listD: List<D>
)
```

Then

```
data class BWithCWithD(
    @Embedded
    val b: B,
    @Relation(....)
    val listCwithD: List<CWithD>
)
```

Then finally

```
data class Full(
    @Embdded
    val a: A,
    @Relation(....)
    val listBWithCWithD: List<BWithCWithD>
)
```

**Working DEMO**

Consider the following Entities, POJOs, `@Dao` annotated interface and `@Database` annotated abstract class:-

```
@Entity
data class A(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val AName: String=""
)
@Entity
data class B(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val parentId: Long,
    val BName: String=""
)
@Entity
data class C(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val parentId: Long,
    val CName: String=""
)
@Entity
data class D(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val parentId: Long,
    val DName: String
)

data class CWithD(
    @Embedded
    val c: C,
    @Relation(entity = D::class, entityColumn = "parentId", parentColumn = "id")
    val listD: List<D>
)
data class BWithCWithD(
    @Embedded
    val b: B,
    @Relation(entity = C::class, entityColumn = "parentId", parentColumn = "id")
    val listCWithD: List<CWithD>
)
data class Full(
    @Embedded
    val a: A,
    @Relation(entity = B::class, entityColumn = "parentId", parentColumn = "id")
    val listBWithCWithD: List<BWithCWithD>
)

@Dao
interface MyDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(a: A): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(b: B): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(c: C): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(d: D): Long
    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM a")
    fun getFull(): List<Full>
}

@Database(entities = [A::class,B::class,C::class,D::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class MyDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun getMyDAOs(): MyDAOs

    companion object {
        private var instance: MyDatabase?=null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): MyDatabase {
            if (instance==null) {
                instance=Room.databaseBuilder(context,MyDatabase::class.java,"my.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as MyDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

And then the following Activity Code:-

```
const val DB_VERSION = 1
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: MyDatabase
    lateinit var dao: MyDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = MyDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getMyDAOs()

        val AId = dao.insert(A(AName = "A1"))
        val B1Id = dao.insert(B(parentId = AId, BName =  "B1"))
        val B2Id = dao.insert(B(parentId = AId, BName = "B2"))
        val C1Id = dao.insert(C(parentId = B1Id, CName = "C1"))
        val C2Id = dao.insert(C(parentId = B2Id, CName = "C2"))
        val C3Id = dao.insert(C(parentId = B1Id, CName = "C3"))
        val C4Id = dao.insert(C(parentId = B1Id, CName = "C4"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C1Id, DName = "D1"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C2Id, DName = "D2"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C3Id, DName = "D3"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C4Id, DName = "D4"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C1Id, DName = "D5"))
        dao.insert(D(parentId = C1Id, DName = "D6"))

        for (a in dao.getFull()) {
            val sb_blist = StringBuilder()
            for (b in a.listBWithCWithD) {
                val sb_clist = StringBuilder()
                for (c in b.listCWithD) {
                    val sb_dlist = StringBuilder()
                    for (d in c.listD) {
                        sb_dlist.append("\n\t\t\tDNAME is ${d.DName} ID is ${d.id} PARENT is ${d.parentId}")
                    }
                    sb_clist.append("\n\t\tCNAME is ${c.c.CName} ID is ${c.c.id} PARENT is ${c.c.parentId}. It has ${c.listD.size} D's; They Are:-${sb_dlist}")
                }
                sb_blist.append("\n\tBNAME is ${b.b.BName} ID is ${b.b.id} PARENT is ${b.b.parentId}. It has ${b.listCWithD.size} C's; They are:-${sb_clist}")
            }
            Log.d("DBINFO","ANAME is ${a.a.AName} ID is ${a.a.id}. It has ${a.listBWithCWithD.size} B's; They are:-${sb_blist}")
        }
   }
}
```

i.e.

- 1 A is inserted, it has;

  - 2 B's as children;

    - The first B has 3 C children, the second has 1 C child

      - Each of the 4 C's have a D child, the first D has an additional 2 children

As is confirmed by the output to the Log using the **Full** pojo (along with the inherited Lists):-

```
D/DBINFO: ANAME is A1 ID is 1. It has 2 B's; They are:-
        BNAME is B1 ID is 1 PARENT is 1. It has 3 C's; They are:-
            CNAME is C1 ID is 1 PARENT is 1. It has 3 D's; They Are:-
                DNAME is D1 ID is 1 PARENT is 1
                DNAME is D5 ID is 5 PARENT is 1
                DNAME is D6 ID is 6 PARENT is 1
            CNAME is C3 ID is 3 PARENT is 1. It has 1 D's; They Are:-
                DNAME is D3 ID is 3 PARENT is 3
            CNAME is C4 ID is 4 PARENT is 1. It has 1 D's; They Are:-
                DNAME is D4 ID is 4 PARENT is 4
        BNAME is B2 ID is 2 PARENT is 1. It has 1 C's; They are:-
            CNAME is C2 ID is 2 PARENT is 2. It has 1 D's; They Are:-
                DNAME is D2 ID is 2 PARENT is 2
```

Using App Inspection and the original query that you quoted (adjusted to show all data and to take into account the fact that I omitted the underscores in the column names) this shows:-

[image]

**Additional re comment**

You say

> Try it. Its works if i use only "CWithD". If I add "BWithCWithD" I get errors: 1.Cannot find the child entity column parent_id in CWithD . 2. [ksp] : The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView. 3. BWithCWithD: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).

I have tried it, e.g. the demo above.

Your issue is that you have either implicitly or explicitly given a class that is not `@Entity` annotated (and defined via the entities parameter of the `@Database` annotation).

More specifically, the `entity` parameter or lack thereof is used to ascertain the table that is to be queried (Room's equivalent of a JOIN).

If you have provided `entity = ?::class` then ? must be the relevant class that is annotated with `@Entity` and **NOT** a POJO.

if you have not specified a class via the `entity` parameter, then the class associated with the variable will be considered the class. In the case that the `@Relation` is for a POJO. Then Room assumes that the table name will be derived from the class.

If the class either explicit or implicit is a POJO then Room will issue the not an entity class (basically the same for DataViews hence the message also catering for that scenario).

Comment: Try it.  Its works if i use only  "CWithD".    If I add "BWithCWithD" I get errors: 1.Cannot find the child entity column `parent_id` in CWithD .  2. [ksp] : The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView.   3. BWithCWithD:   Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).

Comment: @Sergei The answer now has a working example.

Comment: thank you so much for such a detailed answer.   indeed, my mistake was in incorrectly filling out the @Relation. in the entity,   need   @Relation(entity = C::class .....)  val listCWithD: List<CWithD>    but I wrote  @Relation(entity = CWithD::class .....)  val listCWithD: List<CWithD>